# Handling special characters while reading from csv file

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

While reading the data from file `inputstreamreader` converts special characters into replacement character.
For e.g. BleȬÁno is converted into Ble?Áno

My code is :

```
public String getUploadFileAsString() {
    try {
        final InputStream stream = file.getInputStream();
        final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(stream, writer, IrisHttpCommon.UTF8Charset);
        return writer.toString();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new IrisException("exception in getUploadFileAsString()", e);
    }
}
```

I have tried `IOUtils`, `CharStream`, `Scanner`, `BufferedReader`, `InputStreamReader` but nothing solves the problem.

Comment: What is the type of the `file` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Write the file in UTF-8 like this

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(targetFile), "UTF-8"));
```

targetFile is the instance of file in which you want to write content.

Same way applies for reading the content of file.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(sourceFile, "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Java 8 you could try:

```
Path path = Paths.get(...);
Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path, charset)) {
  return br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Specyfing correct input [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.But the problem is with the encoding.
File should have the charset which you are using in your code.
I have changed the encoding to UTF-8 through notepad++ and now its working.